# Capture specific telegram group messages with Telethon python

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, telegram, telethon

Good evening everyone.

I'm trying to get messages from a specific telegram group, using telethon. Can anyone give me a light? I can already get messages from my bot, but how to get messages from other conversations?

Sorry if this post is in the wrong place.

```
async def main():

me = await client.get_me()

async for message in client.iter_messages('me'):
    print(message.id, message.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`iter_messages`](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.iter_messages) docs.

It takes `entity` as first argument:

> The entity from whom to retrieve the message history.

So, replace `client.iter_messages('me')` with `client.iter_messages(chat_id)` in your code